# Exist and Not Exists Query Misunderstanding?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, relational-algebra

Consider the following schema of a product database:

- `Parts` (pid, pname)
- `Suppliers` (sid, sname)
- `Catalog` (sid, pid)

`sid` in `Catalog` is a foreign key and references `Suppliers` and `pid` in `Catalog` is a foreign key and references the `Parts` table. `(s1, p1)` in `Catalog` table shows supplier `s1` produces `p1`.

If I want find details of `Parts` that are not supplied by some suppliers, how we can do this? I read some parts as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM parts P
WHERE ....... (SELECT S.sid 
               FROM suppliers 
                WHERE .....
                       (SELECT * 
                        FROM catalog C 
                        WHERE s.sid = C.sid AND P.pid = C.pid))
```

My problem is via - why at first? We use exist and in second ... we use not exist?

Comment: Re "find details of Parts that are not supplied by some suppliers" This is unclear. Please edit the clear language from your comments into your question. Re your 1st question "how we can do this?" See my updated answer. Re your 2nd question "My problem is via - why at first? We use exist and in second ... we use not exist?" A "why" question assumes shared simpler concepts. Please edit your question. Explain what kind of "why" answer you want. Explain why EXISTS & NOT EXISTS is a "problem". Otherwise the answer is "because your expectations are based on wrong ideas". See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I want find details of `Parts` that are not supplied by some suppliers, how we can do this?

If you want "details for parts where there exists a supplier that doesn't supply that part" then your query, with `EXISTS` then `NOT EXISTS`, is correct.

> My problem is via - why at first? We use exist and in second ... we use not exist?

I will explain why "details for parts where there exists a supplier that doesn't supply that part" can give your query. (With `EXISTS` then `NOT EXISTS`.)

A table holds that rows that make some *predicate* (statement template) into a true *proposition* (statement):

- `Parts` "part P.pid is named P.pname"
- `Suppliers` "supplier S.sid is named S.sname"
- `Catalog` "supplier C.sid supplies part C.pid"

You need to express the predicate for your result. You want the `P.pid`-`P.pname` rows that make a true statement from this:

```
    "part P.pid is named P.pname"
AND EXISTS S.sid ["supplier S.sid is named something"
        AND NOT "supplier S.sid supplies part P.pid"]
```

But we must express this predicate in terms of *the given predicates* (plus conditions and logic operators) so that the DBMS can calculate the rows that satisfy it:

```
    "part P.pid is named P.pname"
AND EXISTS S.sid [EXISTS S.sname "supplier S.sid is named S.sname"
        AND NOT EXISTS C.sid, C.pid [
                "supplier C.sid supplies part P.pid" AND C.sid = S.sid AND C.pid = P.pid]]
```

Now convert to SQL:

- initial *predicate of T* becomes `FROM`*`T`*
- AND *predicate of T* becomes `JOIN`*`T`*
- AND *condition* becomes `WHERE`*`condition`* or `ON`*`condition`*
- outermost EXISTS *dropped columns* becomes `SELECT`*`kept columns`*
- other EXISTS *all columns of T* [*predicate of T*] becomes `EXISTS (`*`T`*`)`

```
SELECT *
FROM Parts P
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT S.sid FROM Suppliers S
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Catalog C
               WHERE C.sid = S.sid AND C.pid = P.pid))
```

*PS* Your question's original "details of parts that are not supplied by some suppliers" is unclear/ambiguous. It could mean `P.id`-`P.pname` pairs where:

1. "the parts are not supplied by all the suppliers" (the interpretation agreeing with your SQL)
2. "the parts are not not supplied (by any of the suppliers)" (the interpretation agreeing with the two SQL versions in [Shnugo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35399183/3404097)
3. "the parts don't have multiple suppliers"

   ```
   SELECT * FROM Parts P
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
       FROM Catalog C1 JOIN Catalog C2 ON C1.sid <> C2.sid
       AND C1.pid = P.pid AND C2.pid = P.pid)
   ```

If you have `Parts` 1-4 and `Suppliers` 1-3 then the above give three different answers after:

```
INSERT INTO Catalog VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3);
```

*PPS* Logic formulations for the above are:

```
-- 1. "the parts are not supplied by all the suppliers"  
    P(P.pid, P.pname)
AND EXISTS S.sid, S.sname [S(S.sid, S.sname) AND NOT C(S.sid, P.pid)]
-- 2 "the parts are not supplied (by some of the suppliers)"
P(P.pid, P.pname) AND NOT EXISTS C.sid C(C.sid, P.pid)
-- 3. "the parts don't have multiple suppliers"
    P(P.pid, P.pname)
AND NOT EXISTS C1.sid, C2.sid
        [C(C1.sid, P.pid) AND C(C2.sid, P.pid) AND C1.sid <> C2.sid]
```

Answer (score 2):

Wasn't it simple as that? If not please use my example tables and specify your expected output:

```
DECLARE @Parts TABLE(pid INT, pname VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @Suppliers TABLE(sid INT, sname VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @Catalog TABLE(pid INT, sid INT);

INSERT INTO @Parts VALUES(1,'Part 1'),(2,'Part 2'),(3,'Part 3'),(4,'Part 4');
INSERT INTO @Suppliers VALUES(1,'Suppl 1'),(2,'Suppl 2'),(3,'Suppl 3');
INSERT INTO @Catalog VALUES(1,1),(1,3) --part 1 from two suppliers
                          ,(2,1)       --part 2 from one supplier
                                       --part 3 no supplier
                                       --part 4 no supplier

--Get all parts *that not supplied by some suppliers*
SELECT * 
FROM @Parts AS p 
WHERE p.pid NOT IN(SELECT c.pid FROM @Catalog AS c)
```

The result

```
pid pname
3   Part 3
4   Part 4
```

#### EDIT: The same is reached with "your" query, but this would perform worse:

This query is looking for parts, where there is **no** supplier which **does** have an entry in "catalog". And I must admit, this smells a bit like homework :-)

```
SELECT * FROM @Parts P 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT S.sid 
                  FROM @Suppliers S 
                  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                FROM @Catalog C 
                                WHERE s.sid = C.sid AND P.pid = C.pid
                                )
                  )
```