# Confused about NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql

"Find the names of sailors who have reserved all boats."

SQL code:

```
SELECT S.sname
FROM Sailors S
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT B.bid
                   FROM Boats B WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT R. bid
                                                   FROM Reserves R            
                                                   WHERE R.bid = B.bid
                                                   AND R.sid = S.sid ))
```

Could anyone please explain/translate the above sql code? Why is there `NOT EXISTS` but not `IN`. And why is value checking happens in the innermost subquery `(WHERE R.bid = B.bid AND R.sid = S.sid)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Comment: @Igor, that's only the part of the question

Comment: Then what are you confused on exactly? Have you already looked at the documentation and examples  on MSDN? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

Comment: @Igor, im confused about the logic of NOT EXIST. the problem states `"Find the names of sailors who have reserved all boats."`, but what im confused about is what does `NOT EXISTS` do here ? Why not use `EXISTS` ?

Comment: @Igor, could you please translate the sql code into plain english ??

Comment: Right, and how do you determine if a sailor has reserved ALL boats? Well, another way to think about that is: there does NOT EXIST a boat that the sailor hasn't reserved.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398701/exist-and-not-exists-query-misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

"Sailor S has reserved all boats" is logically equivalent to "there does not exist a boat that Sailor S has not reserved".  This gives you the first layer of the query:

```
SELECT S.sname
FROM Sailors S
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT B.bid
                   FROM Boats B WHERE ...
```

"Sailor S has not reserved boat B" is logically equivalent to "there does not exist a reservation for boat B by sailor S".  This produces the final piece the second subquery:

```
NOT EXISTS ( SELECT R. bid
               FROM Reserves R            
               WHERE R.bid = B.bid
                AND R.sid = S.sid )
```

In this innermost subquery, `B.bid` and `S.sid` refer back to the tables referenced in the outer query blocks. This is called a correlated subquery, and means it is evaluated separately for each row produced by other outer query, using the values from that row.